# Turning off Microsoft Surface Dial Sleep Mode

Tags: windows, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

while developing for the new Microsoft Surface Dial I noticed the device going to sleep after a few minutes and taking about 1-2 seconds to wake up again after an interaction with the device. This is insufficient for my specific use case, where the application has to give immediate feedback.

I've tried turning off the energy settings for the bluetooth device in the device manager, but the problem persists. Is there a way to turn this off, either in code or in some other way?

Comment: If I had more reputation I'd assign a bounty; this is really obnoxious behavior as a user. I hope it's not intrinsic to Bluetooth LE? I'm considering returning my Dial and going with something wired, despite the lack of Dial-specific features.

Comment: I use it as a system volume knob, the lag is indeed quite annoying. I also wish you didn't have to click and hold to choose volume even though I have volume set as the only allowed tool in the settings...There should be an option to "Use Surface Dial for One Purpose and Always Stay Active"

Comment: I think there is no excuse for the Surface Dial to be more laggy than a mouse or a keyboard. Input device feedback should be as instantaneous as possible. That's why I keep thinking this must be a bug or a setting I have configured incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to solve the issue without a Microsoft firmware update.
The unit use a Nordic Semiconductor nRF52832 Bluetooth Low Energy SoC, is possible change that on the chip, but with a firmware update. Really sorry but is the only way.